# Creating a Google Data Studio GPS report, using data from two sources in Big Query - scheduled report data and real-time data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I'd like to prefix this post by saying I'm an SQL novice, new to BigQuery and a first time poster, so thanks in advance!

I'm currently recreating a report in Google Data Studio that was originally built in Excel for a bus company which would compare a daily schedule with data we receive daily from a third-party software. The 'Schedule' data table includes the route name, location names, the scheduled times and GPS coordinates. The 'Real-time' data that we receive from third-party software includes: the date, timestamp for every 40 seconds and the GPS coordinates for that time stamp. Note, there is no 'route name', this is key for later in my question.

The third-party CSV data is uploaded daily as individual CSV files to a Google Cloud Data Storage bucket, which is in turn connected to Google BigQuery as one, single Real-Time data table, ready to be compared against the Schedule data table.

The aim of this report is to be able to compare the uploaded Real-Time data table against the Schedule data, to create a Google Data Studio report that our logistics team can check to answer the two main questions: 1) Punctuality of the bus - was the bus on time that day and if it was late, by how much. 2) Location of the bus - where is the exact GPS location of the bus in relation the scheduled GPS coordinates, per time stamp. My ideal report would have filters to select different Bus Routes and choose the Date in question.

My first query lies in how to construct this report. I envision that I will need to perform a join with my data, to be explicit, two LEFT joins that answer my two key questions as follows: 1) Punctuality calculation through a left join via GPS coordinates and, 2) GPS calculation through a left join via the timestamps.

If that outline is clear and my proposal to use two LEFT joins is correct, which I suspect may not be so for reasons discussed below, let's move on to stage two. This is a good checkpoint for anyone who has read up until this point and believes I need to make changes to my approach.

Moving on, when and if I join my two tables, I have initially observed the following technical considerations that I will need a little bit of help with:

1) Timestamps in the Real-Time data are taken every 40 seconds. Therefore, I don't necessarily have data for the bus at exact time stamps e.g. the bus in my Schedule is meant to be at location x for 09:00:00, however, my closest timestamp in my Real-Time data might be 09:00:04. How do I match that data to select the correct data point. Initially, I thought about reducing the number of significant figures, however, I then considered the instance, that would be observed in this example where I would also have a data point at 09:00:44, 40 seconds later. With reduced significant figures - 09:00, there would be two matching data points and they would be treated as the same. Any idea? Maybe a LEFT join with MIN.

2) GPS coordinates to be matched. I've attempted to use the ST_CLOSESTPOINT Geography function but I don't fully understand it ST_CLOSESTPOINT(geography_1, geography_2[, spheroid=FALSE]). What is spheroid=FALSE?(https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions).

3) Thirdly and currently my most difficult issue, my Real-Time data table is linked to a Google Data bucket with over a years worth of CSV files, for 9 different buses with different routes - 1 CSV file per bus, per day. Also, as mentioned in paragraph 2, there is no 'route name' in my Real-Time data, just a bunch on GPS coordinates and time stamps. I need to think of a way to be able differentiate between these different CSV files with my Schedule data table, so that it will be functional in Google Data studio with the two filters previously mentioned, to firstly select the Bus Routes and then select the date. It is this point that makes me question if a LEFT join is appropriate as this functionality would not be possible with data already joined. Currently, with a large Real-Time data set, a join with my Schedule data table is randomly matching with the nearest closest of this data set, with no capability to select by day etc.

This is quite a big project, a little out of my comfort zone and a long detailed question, but any guidance would be much appreciated as I'm relatively new to SQL and BigQuery.

Many thanks in advance!

```
// JOIN 1 - via ST_CLOSESTPOINT to determine punctuality of the bus


SELECT
r1.Direction,
r1.ScheduledLocation,
r1.ScheduledNextLocation,
r1.ScheduledTime,
r1.ScheduledCoordinates,
r1.ScheduledXCoordinates,
r1.ScheduledYCoordinates,
r1.ScheduledFullCoordinates,
r2.RealTime,
r2.RealTimeDate,
r2.RealTimeXCoordinates,
r2.RealTimeYCoordinates,
r2.RealTimeFullCoordinates,

ST_CLOSESTPOINT(r1.ScheduledFullCoordinates, r2.RealTimeFullCoordinates) as ClosestPoint

FROM `SCHEDULE DATA SOURCE` r1

LEFT JOIN `REAL-TIME DATA SOURCE` r2 ON r1.ScheduledTime = r2.RealTime 



// JOIN 2 - via Timestamp to determine GPS location of the bus
SELECT  
r1.Direction,
r1.ScheduledLocation,
r1.ScheduledNextLocation,
r1.ScheduledTime,
r1.ScheduledCoordinates,
r1.ScheduledXCoordinates,
r1.ScheduledYCoordinates,
r1.ScheduledFullCoordinates,
r2.RealTime,
r2.RealTimeXCoordinates,
r2.RealTimeYCoordinates,
r2.RealTimeFullCoordinates

FROM `SCHEDULE DATA SOURCE` r1

LEFT JOIN `REAL-TIME DATA SOURCE` r2 ON r1.ScheduledTime = r2.RealTime
```

Comment: Hi Edd. Quite a first post! Could you include some example data and what an outcome might look like?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do instead of join is use analytical functions. I assume the data per bus route is small enough for this. If you have multiple bus routes in same query - add PARTITION BY .

I used r1 as sample scheduled time / location, and r2 as real time / location. I then union them and add `sched` flag denoting whether this is scheduled or real time. Then ORDER all events by time, and for each event add previous and next location. You can now filter only scheduled event - for each one you'll have next and previous location. My code is somewhat simplistic, as it may choose previous or next scheduled event, rather than previous or next real event. But if real events are collected often enough that is unlikely to happen.

Finally, about ST_CLOSESTPOINT - the function is used to find a point of one complex shape closest to another complex shape. I don't think you'll need it, as you deal with points, so it just returns the single available point, i.e. its first argument. What you need is ST_DISTANCE to calculate distance to the real point. I calculate two distances, to previous real event and to next real event, and choose one that is closer.

```
with r1 as (
    select time(10, 0, 0) as sched_tm, ST_GeogPoint(10, 10) as sched_loc union all
    select time(10, 10, 0) as sched_tm, ST_GeogPoint(11, 11) as sched_loc union all
    select time(10, 20, 0) as sched_tm, ST_GeogPoint(12, 13) as sched_loc 
), r2 as (
    select time(10, 0, 10) as real_tm, ST_GeogPoint(10.1, 10) as real_loc union all
    select time(10, 0, 50) as real_tm, ST_GeogPoint(10.2, 10) as real_loc union all
    select time(10, 9, 40) as real_tm, ST_GeogPoint(10.9, 11) as real_loc union all
    select time(10, 10, 20) as real_tm, ST_GeogPoint(11.1, 11) as real_loc union all
    select time(10, 20, 0) as real_tm, ST_GeogPoint(12, 13) as real_loc 
), r12 as (
    select TRUE as sched, sched_tm tm, sched_loc as loc from r1 
    union all 
    select FALSE as sched, real_tm tm, real_loc as loc from r2
), r12_sort as (
    select sched, tm, loc, 
           LAG(loc, 1) OVER(ORDER BY tm) as prev_loc, 
           LEAD(loc, 1) OVER(ORDER BY tm) as next_loc 
    from r12 
)
select sched, tm as sched_tm, loc, prev_loc, next_loc, 
     LEAST(coalesce(st_distance(loc, prev_loc), 1e9),
           coalesce(st_distance(loc, next_loc), 1e9)) as distance
from r12_sort
where sched
```

The result is like this:

```
Line sched  sched_tm  loc           prev_loc        next_loc         distance   
1    true   10:00:00  POINT(10 10)  null            POINT(10.1 10)   10950.579731746193
2    true   10:10:00  POINT(11 11)  POINT(10.9 11)  POINT(11.1 11)   10915.213347763152
3    true   10:20:00  POINT(12 13)  POINT(11.1 11)  POINT(12 13)     0.0
```